# Parser Error: ")" expected

Tags: c#, monodevelop

Ok, I'm using C# on MonoDevelop 2.4 and I got this weird error:

[image: Weird Error]

The tooltip says that it's a 'Parser Error: ")" expected.' Funny thing is: it works! Compiles and runs without a hitch.

The only problem is, the entire class doesn't show up in the classes pad. How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Report a bug to the developers of the IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that MonoDevelop doesn't understand optional parameters yet... or at least the version you're using doesn't - even though the compiler itself does.

Comment: It looks that way, the [release notes](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.6) for version 2.6 say "C# 4.0 named arguments and optional parameters have been fully implemented. "